# How to send multiple Get request

Tags: php

In my script i have an array which filelocations on my server. i would like to send multiple header/get to another page were it will delete these files.

my delete page uses `$_GET` to se which file to delete.

```
$array1 = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3');

foreach($array1 as $key => $item){
echo '<li><a href="delete_page.php?file='.$item.'">'.$item.'</a></li>';
}
```

delete file

```
$_delete=$_GET['file'];
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM Doc WHERE file=$file");
```

How could i send multiple headers without post but instead use get?
instead of forcing user to click all the links to delete the items?

Comment: Have a look at CURL. Oh and more important : 1) The `DELETE` method is suitable to use (when possible) when deleting stuff. 2) You should check very carefully that the people requesting the delete has the right to delete this file, else you might expose yourself to big trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple ids with following URL:

```
delete_page.php?files[]=file1&files[]=file2&files[]=file3
```

Generate it with:

```
$files = array();
foreach ($array1 as $item){
  $files[] = 'files[]=' . $item;
}
$items = implode('&', $files);
echo '<li><a href="delete_page.php?' . $items . '">delete all</a></li>';
```

Handle it with:

```
$_delete = $_GET['files'];
$files = implode(',', $_delete);
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM Doc WHERE file IN ($files)");
```

However this simple solution is vulnerable to sql injection.

You should better work on files IDs and during the SQL build, parse all passed ids with

```
$_delete = array_map('intval', $_GET['files']);
```

Comment: And you could also use a checkbox instead `<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="filenameHere">` then a submit button. So the user can choose the files to be deleted by clicking.

Comment: Actually im using params however i did this to simplfy alot. I´ve already done it with arrays, i was curious if it was possible to send multiple get to page.